# How can I pick up the blockchain download where it left off on another computer using an EHD?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, synchronization

I started downloading the Bitcoin blockchain via my MacBook Pro onto my 1TB external hard drive. I want to use my iMac to finish the download. I plugged my EHD into my iMac and checked to blocks folder and it contained the previous transaction I downloaded (86GB). The wallet.dat, peers.dat, chainstate, banlist.dat and fee_estimates.dat files. I opened Bitcoin Core and moved the directory to the blocks folder where the previous transaction I downloaded are. I followed the steps to start the sync. I expected the blockchain to recognize the blocks and start where it left off on my MacBook but it started from the beginning. Any ideas on how to pick up where I left off?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even if you transfer all the data from a fully synced client, the bitcoin client still needs to validate those blocks. It will still take a while, but should be quicker than downloading all the data and verifying.

ANSWER IS NOT ACCURATE.
EDIT: If you copy the chainstate, there shouldn't be any work the receiving system should perform anymore - the software wouldn't even know it was moved. It's possible the wrong directory was used.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping that was the case and yes, it is moving faster than before.

Comment: If you copy the chainstate, there shouldn't be any work the receiving system should perform anymore - the software wouldn't even know it was moved.

Comment: Downvote. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: Pieter, any ideas why his client would still be still syncing?

Comment: My best guess is that he used the wrong directory.

Comment: Answer has now been edited.

Comment: I completed the blockchain download. My Core wallet still takes ~5 minutes to sync an hour of transactions. If I were to wait a week to resync my wallet it would take at least 8 hours. This seems fairly long and inconvenient. If I can't find a better solution I may settle with using my less secure MultiBit desktop client.